# Truffle Drizzle-box fails with TypeError: (0 , _drizzle.generateContractsInitialState) is not a function

Tags: web3js, truffle, metamask, ganache, drizzle

Right after unboxing Drizzle-box I'm getting a
`TypeError: (0 , _drizzle.generateContractsInitialState) is not a function.`

Ganache is running on localhost:8545, contracts are deployed, Metamask connected to localhost:8545, as it should. What I did wrong? Please help!

Comment: I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to bump the version of drizzle in package.json.
If you do `npm list drizzle` you might be on `1.0.1`. 
I did `npm upgrade drizzle` and `1.1.0` fixed the issue.

Now I have new issues :-\

Comment: I've checked - I have drizzle@1.1.0 :-(.

Comment: I got the issue stated in the question and after carrying out this step I am now getting the issue as reported here: https://github.com/truffle-box/drizzle-box/issues/15

Comment: @am17torres What is your new issue?

Comment: I fixed my issue by changing my Metamask network to: localhost:8545.

Comment: @Calum - It's just stuck "Loading  dapp...". The console says "Cannot read property 'address' of undefined." I have metamask connected to localhost 8545. My account id matches the first account id printed from `ganache-cli -b 3`

Comment: Not exactly sure how I got this working but I did `truffle console` `truffle compile` `truffle migrate` and after all that `yarn start` got the UI loading.

Comment: @am17torres - "Cannot read property 'address' of undefined." means that you need to deploy your contracts. Other thing you need to assure - that your metamask plugin connected to the same network (with the same mnemonic). Use this in your truffle-config.js:         development: {
            provider: function() {
                return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "http://localhost:8545/");
            },
            network_id: '*',
        },

Answer (score 2):

I had to update, drizzle-react & drizzle-react-component to 1.1.0

```
npm i drizzle-react@1.1.0 drizzle-react-component@1.1.0
```

seems to be working fine after doing so.

Comment: you got a typo: it's drizzle-react-components (s at the end)

Answer (score 0):

this error is caused by drizzle package so 
to get rid of this error i've compiled the box myself :

git clone https://github.com/truffle-box/drizzle-box.git

then i've edited the package.json file to change the drizzle version:

```
 "drizzle": "1.1.5",
```

then

- npm install
- truffle compile
- truffle migrate
- npm run start

NB : There is a patch for this issue :
check this pull request https://github.com/trufflesuite/drizzle/pull/95

Here's my package.json file :

```
  "dependencies": {

    "drizzle": "1.1.5",

    "drizzle-react": "1.1.1",

    "drizzle-react-components": "^1.1.0",

    "react": "^16.4.1",

    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",

    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",

    "redux": "^4.0.0",

    "eth-block-tracker-es5": "^2.3.2",

    "web3": "1.0.0-beta.34",

    "eth-block-tracker-es5": "^2.3.2",

    "react-redux": "^5.0.2",

    "react-router": "^3.0.2",

    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.7",

    "redux-auth-wrapper": "^1.0.0",

    "redux-saga": "^0.15.3",

    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"



  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update several libraries by doing the following:

1. npm update drizzle
2. npm update drizzle-react
3. npm update drizzle-react-components

Then: truffle compile, truffle migrate, npm run start