# Truffle unbox drizzle not working properly

Tags: truffle, nodejs, react, drizzle

truffle version = 4.1.4

```
truffle unbox drizzle
truffle compile
truffle migrate
npm run build
npm run start
```

this gets me this error:

```
Truffle Drizzle-box fails with TypeError: (0 , _drizzle.generateContractsInitialState) is not a function
```

I can solve this with an answer from [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/44032/truffle-drizzle-box-fails-with-typeerror-0-drizzle-generatecontractsinitial) question

this brings me to this new error.

```
uncaught at l Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `Home`.
```

and

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$iugbinqqxet' of null
```

CONTENTS OF HOME.JS:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { AccountData, ContractData, ContractForm } from 'drizzle-react-components'
import logo from '../../logo.png'

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <main className="container">
        <div className="pure-g">
          <div className="pure-u-1-1 header">
            <img src={logo} alt="drizzle-logo" />
            <h1>Drizzle Examples</h1>
            <p>Examples of how to get started with Drizzle in various situations.</p>

            <br/><br/>
          </div>

          <div className="pure-u-1-1">
            <h2>Active Account</h2>
            <AccountData accountIndex="0" units="ether" precision="3" />

            <br/><br/>
          </div>

          <div className="pure-u-1-1">
            <h2>SimpleStorage</h2>
            <p>This shows a simple ContractData component with no arguments, along with a form to set its value.</p>
            <p><strong>Stored Value</strong>: <ContractData contract="SimpleStorage" method="storedData" /></p>
            <ContractForm contract="SimpleStorage" method="set" />

            <br/><br/>
          </div>

          <div className="pure-u-1-1">
            <h2>TutorialToken</h2>
            <p>Here we have a form with custom, friendly labels. Also note the token symbol will not display a loading indicator. We've suppressed it with the <code>hideIndicator</code> prop because we know this variable is constant.</p>
            <p><strong>Total Supply</strong>: <ContractData contract="TutorialToken" method="totalSupply" methodArgs={[{from: this.props.accounts[0]}]} /> <ContractData contract="TutorialToken" method="symbol" hideIndicator /></p>
            <p><strong>My Balance</strong>: <ContractData contract="TutorialToken" method="balanceOf" methodArgs={[this.props.accounts[0]]} /></p>
            <h3>Send Tokens</h3>
            <ContractForm contract="TutorialToken" method="transfer" labels={['To Address', 'Amount to Send']} />

            <br/><br/>
          </div>

          <div className="pure-u-1-1">
            <h2>ComplexStorage</h2>
            <p>Finally this contract shows data types with additional considerations. Note in the code the strings below are converted from bytes to UTF-8 strings and the device data struct is iterated as a list.</p>
            <p><strong>String 1</strong>: <ContractData contract="ComplexStorage" method="string1" toUtf8 /></p>
            <p><strong>String 2</strong>: <ContractData contract="ComplexStorage" method="string2" toUtf8 /></p>
            <strong>Single Device Data</strong>: <ContractData contract="ComplexStorage" method="singleDD" />

            <br/><br/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    )
  }
}

export default Home
```

Comment: where you able to make this work? we are also stuck here

Comment: check my answer here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/44032/truffle-drizzle-box-fails-with-typeerror-0-drizzle-generatecontractsinitial

Answer (score 1):

Update several libraries by doing the following:

npm update drizzle
npm update drizzle-react
npm update drizzle-react-components
Then: truffle compile, truffle migrate, npm run start